# MySQL "Group By" from two joined queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have produced the query below which returns the following results:

```
mysql> select u.username, s.campaignno, if(f.hometeamscore>f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Win, f.hometeamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.hometeamid and s.user_id = u.id union all
    -> select u.username, s.campaignno, if(f.awayteamscore>f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Win, f.awayteamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.awayteamid and s.user_id = u.id;
+------------+------------+-----+-------+
| username   | campaignno | Win | Goals |
+------------+------------+-----+-------+
| tingeyal   |   34910256 |   1 |     5 |
| shanu      |   35410256 |   1 |     4 |
| tingeyal   |   34910256 |   0 |     0 |
| kOS        |   35210256 |   1 |     2 |
| kOS        |   35210256 |   0 |     0 |
| shanu      |   35410256 |   1 |     3 |
| kriste8403 |   35510256 |   1 |     3 |
| kriste8403 |   35510256 |   0 |     0 |
+------------+------------+-----+-------+
8 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

However, I wish to return just one line for each username & campaignno combination summing both the "Win" and "Goals" columns.  In the above instance I would like the query to return the following:

```
+------------+------------+-----+-------+
| username   | campaignno | Win | Goals |
+------------+------------+-----+-------+
| tingeyal   |   34910256 |   1 |     5 |
| shanu      |   35410256 |   2 |     7 |
| kOS        |   35210256 |   1 |     2 |
| kriste8403 |   35510256 |   1 |     3 |
+------------+------------+-----+-------+
4 rows in set (0.01 sec)
```

I believe this will involve the group by?  Or maybe I have to create a new query and combine it with this one.  As you can see I am unsure on what my next steps should be.  If anyone thinks it would be helpful to have the table details then just let me know.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I believe this will involve the group by?

Yes, it will. To get the desired result, you don't have to write separate query. Try following.

```
SELECT tablea.username, tablea.campaignno, SUM(tablea.Win) Win, SUM(tablea.Goals) Goals 
FROM
(select u.username, s.campaignno, if(f.hometeamscore>f.awayteamscore,1,0) as Win, f.hometeamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.hometeamid and s.user_id = u.id 
union all
select u.username, s.campaignno, if(f.awayteamscore>f.hometeamscore,1,0) as Win, f.awayteamscore as Goals from straightred_fixture f, straightred_userselection s, auth_user u where s.fixtureid = f.fixtureid and s.teamselectionid = f.awayteamid and s.user_id = u.id) AS tablea
WHERE 1
GROUP BY tablea.username
```

Above query will create a temp table `tablea` containing data of both sub-queries and fetch required data.

Comment: Many thanks for swift response.  Simple yet genius.  I will accept the answer shortly as apparently it is too early to accept it.

Comment: That GROUP BY wont execute on newer MySQL versions. (Unless in compatibility mode.) The general GROUP BY rule says: If a GROUP BY clause is specified, each column reference in the SELECT list must either identify a grouping column or be the argument of a set function!